# How do I get a news article thumbnail from a url in React HTML?

Tags: html, reactjs, thumbnails

I'm getting a list of CNBC articles from a backend api and I'm trying to create a newsfeed from these articles.
The articles are formatted as:

```
{
title: //title of article,
description: //description of article,
url: //link to CNN article
}
```

I'm trying to make the articles as thumbnails, like this:
[image]

I'm trying to use `link` tags, but those don't seem to work. Any suggestions/ideas to generate the thumbnail from the url?
If it helps, an example link is as follows: https://www.cnbc.com/2023/01/03/ford-f-series-2022-sales-show-pickup-continued-decades-long-dominance.html

Comment: You cannot generate a thumbnail from a URL. The backend API would have to return a link to the thumbnail image as well. If you were to render on the backend you could crawl the link for the thumbnail. In this case you would want to look for the og:image meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

## [url-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-metadata/v/2.4.1)

```bash
npm i url-metadata@2.4.1
```

```bash
yarn add url-metadata@2.4.1
```

url-metadata request an http(s) url and scrape its metadata. Many of the metadata fields returned are Open Graph Protocol (og:) so far.

Under the hood, this package does some post-request processing on top of the request module.